# What does "shoveling mud" means?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching TV show 'Shark Tank'. One person asked, "How did you earn your money?" then competitor answered

> YMCA. Shoveling mud. Everything you can think of.

Does this mean he actually shoveled the mud literally? Did he shoveled the mud at YMCA? Is that a job that you can get paid? like industrial work? or does it mean idiomatically he did hard things? I tried to find 'shoveling mud' in google but nothing really came out.

I found the video of it for context.
https://youtu.be/S9eTGdfKQV8
it started around 1:45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not having watched the video clip, but just from your quote it seems pretty clear.  He is listing jobs he's had in the past. Each one is different:

- YMCA
- shoveling mud
- Everything you could think of

Shoveling mud might be done is certain construction jobs, street repair, etc. How often do you have to "shovel *dirt*"?  How about when planting trees? Or landscaping? Or digging a foundation of a house. There are various tasks which require it.

> Does this mean he actually shoveled the mud literally?

yes

> Did he shoveled the mud at YMCA?

no

> like industrial work?

yes

> or does it mean idiomatically he did hard things?

"shoveling mud" is not an idiom. However, if you said "shoveling mud, and things like that", it would conjure up an image of manual labor.

> I tried to find 'shoveling mud' in google but nothing really came out.

It's not a set phrase.

> Is that a job that you can get paid?

Of course, the above mentioned jobs would be paid, although usually not a very high wage.